# Method name is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

I have problem in calling the method in my module.

`There is an errorTypeError: usr.User.getAddress is not a function`

I don't know how to fix this I think I have problem in my module code. I want to get the address or the result.

in my main.js

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var usr = require('./user');

  var useraddress = usr.User.getAddress (id,pool); //this is how I access the method
```

in my user.js

```
exports.User = function () {

    return {
        getAddress: function (userid, pool){
            pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
                var options = {
                    sql: " select address from user where id = ?
                };

                var querypos = connection.query(options, [userid], function (err, results) {
                    if (err) throw err;


                });

            });
        }
   };

};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are exporting `User` as a factory function which returns an object with `getAddress` method on it. So you need to invoke (instantiate) `User` first:

```
var useraddress = usr.User().getAddress(id, pool);
```

Another important problem. `connection.query` request is asynchronous, which means that assigning getAddress result to `var useraddress` doesn't make sense. Instead you need to either pass callback to `getAddress` or use Promise pattern (check this post for great deal of details on the topic: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)).

In your case I think something like this would be a simplest working approach:

```
exports.User = function () {
    return {
        getAddress: function (userid, pool){
            pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
                var options = {
                    sql: "select address from user where id = ?"
                };

                var querypos = connection.query(options, [userid], function (err, results, callback, errCallback) {
                    if (err) {
                      errCallback(err);
                    }
                    callback(results);
                });
            });
        }
   };
};
```

and usage:

```
usr.User().getAddress(id, pool, function(result) {
    console.log('Loaded', result);
});
```

Comment: Hi there is no error anymore, but the result of my query is not outputing

Comment: It's because `getAddress` is asynchronous. Check updated post.

Comment: Hi, thank you last one question, how did you know that it is a factory function ?

Comment: Factory function is a function that returns new objects every time you call it. Like in your case when you call `User()` it produces object `{getAddress: function() {...}}`. There is also a whole design pattern (Factory) based on this approach.

Comment: Thank you , your answer is very useful

Comment: No problem, glad it was useful.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `usr.User` does not have `.getAddress` property on it.
To use `.getAddress` as a property, you need to export User as an object instead.

```
exports.User = {
    getAddress: function (userid, pool){
        pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
            var options = {
                sql: " select address from user where id = ?
            };

            var querypos = connection.query(options, [userid], function (err, results) {
                if (err) throw err;


            });

        });
      }
    };
 };
```

Now it does.

Comment: For a *useful* answer, say *what* you changed, and *why*. You've got about half of the why above, and none of the what.